# Python парс данных с Web - сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, python-3.6

Всех приветствую.
Я получаю данные страницы с помощью либы requests. Далее достаю все страницу через requests.text

На странице есть вот такие данные:

```
script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"12345"
```

Мне нужно получать только 12345.
Через BeautifulSoup пробовал. Понял только то, что вытягивать могу по стандартным HTML тегам. Тут же, подобным образом не работает.
Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно регуляркой вытащить из текста:

```
import re
import requests

rs = requests.get(...

m = re.search('"csrf_token":"(.+?)"', rs.text)
csrf_token = m.group(1)
print(csrf_token)
```

Тестирование:

```
text = '''script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"12345"'''
m = re.search('"csrf_token":"(.+?)"', text)
print(m.group(1))
# 12345
```

---

**PS.**

- `"csrf_token":"(.+?)"` -- говорит о поиске этой строки и вытаскивание значения из круглых скобок (через `m.group(1)`).

  [group()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) -- вытаскивание группы захваченных символов, и оно соответствует количеству круглых скобок в регулярном выражении:

  - `0` -- вся строка, описанная в регулярке, т.е. `"csrf_token":"12345"`
  - `1` -- значение в `(.+?)`, т.е. `12345`

    Если были бы еще скобки, то можно было использовать `group(2)`, `group(3)`, ...
- `.+?` -- `.` это в регулярке любой символ, а `+` -- от 1 до конца строки символов, `?` -- говорит регулярке, чтобы поиск был нежадным

Comment: Спасибо, это работает.
Но хотел бы уточнить. Что делает вот это "csrf_token = m.group(1)"?

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите в `PS.`. А так, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)