# Python. Определенное число с web страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

В моем коде есть строки

```
link = 'https://site.com/'
web = requests.get(link)
```

На сайте https://site.com/ есть строка (часть javascript)

```
score ( 12345 ) * 2 }  ;    // comment
```

**score (**  и **) * 2 }  ; // comment** больше на странице нигде не повторяются, значение 12345 может измениться
Как переменной "res" присвоить значение 12345

Answer (score 0):

Вытаскивайте значение регуляркой, например:

```
import re

text = 'score ( 12345 ) * 2 }  ;    // comment'
m = re.search('score \( (\d+) \) \* 2 }  ;    // comment', text)
res = m.group(1)
print(res)
# 12345
```

Для `requests`:

```
link = 'https://site.com/'
rs = requests.get(link)

m = re.search('score \( (\d+) \) \* 2 }  ;    // comment', rs.text)
res = m.group(1)
print(res)
# 12345
```

---

**PS.**

`'score \( (\d+) \) \* 2 }  ;    // comment'` -- это шаблон поиска регулярки, мы в нем говорим, что ищем такую строку, но меняться в ней будет значение внутри `score` -- `(\d+)`.

- `\(` и `\*` нужны для экранирования мета-символов, чтобы они считались обычными символами в строке
- `\d+` означает что будут искаться только цифры
- круглые скобки в `(\d+)` говорят о захвате символом, чтобы вернуть из через `m.group(1)`

Comment: Похожий ответ на подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068367/201445